# Missing Page numbering on first pages in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

**Page Numbering is starting on the Second Page in Crystal Reports.**

I have a crystal report with 3 subreports on 3 different report headers and one of them is a cross tab subreport.

I put the page number on the page footer of the main report. However, the counting line 'Page 1 of x' does not show on page 1 but, start from page 2 shows  "page 2 of x".

I want the page numbering to be shown on all pages. If there are 2 pages to the report output, it shows on the second as page 2 of 2. And, if there are many pages , if only shows on the last page (ex. page 7 of  7). It looks like the line is hidden somewhere.

I moved it to report footer as well instead of page footer but no luck yet.

Would anyone know?

I am using crystal reports 10.

Comment: Put all subreports and cross tab in page footer. That should do it.

Comment: Thank you but i don't understand. So i should remove all the subreport under their respective header sections and put them in page footer? Or should they  all be page footer instead of report headers?

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit. If you have some data (subreport) in group headers, etc, and in report footer your crosstab and page counter, you should put your page counter in page footer, because your section will only render when your crosstab is shown on page, which is on last page. Try that and tell me what changes will happen.